# Why isn't the engine's Case-Throat-Nozzle reusable in Virgin Galactic's SpaceShipTwo?

Tags: engines, reuse, sub-orbital, tourism, virgin-galactic

I raed on https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smithsonian-institution/engine-powering-future-civilian-spaceflight-enters-collections-180971493/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201214005348/https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smithsonian-institution/engine-powering-future-civilian-spaceflight-enters-collections-180971493/)):

> RocketMotorTwo is a hybrid rocket motor that combines the simplicity of a solid propellant rocket engine with the controllability of a liquid propellant engine. The motor consists of two main parts—a large tank which stores the liquid oxidizer (nitrous oxide), and the cartridge which stores hydroxyl-terminated polybutadiene (HTPB) solid fuel. This combination, known as **the Case/Throat/Nozzle (CTN), the guts of the engine, is the portion of RocketMotorTwo donated to the museum. It is one of the only non-reusable components of SpaceShipTwo**.

Why isn't the engine's Case-Throat-Nozzle reusable in Virgin Galactic's SpaceShipTwo?

Comment: For roughly the same reason that a hotdog is not reuseable after eating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question states, a hybrid motor is basically a solid motor with oxidizer piped into it. For the reasons Burt Rutan chose a hybrid motor in the first place, see [Why did Virgin Galactic decide to use a hybrid engine vs liquid on their space ship?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39277/6944)

It's the solid part of the motor that makes reuse difficult. Reusing a solid motor case involves so much cleaning and refurbishing that it can be pretty much a wash as to whether it's just cheaper to make a new one  - as the shuttle program [found out](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/16865/6944) and as discussed here: [Why isn't someone building a fully reusable solid fuel rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19017/6944)